# Python Iterate and print dictionary with a list for values

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with a string for each key and a list for each value like this:

```
dict = {'john': [1,2], 'peter': [3,4], 'stacy': [5,6], 'chad': [7,8]}
```

and I want to iterate through it with a for loop and have the output be like this:

john has 1 and 2
peter has 3 and 4
stacy has 5 and 6
chad has 7 and 8

I wrote the code like this:

```
for keys, values in dict:
    print(f"{keys} has {values[0]} and {values[1]}")
```

but when I run the program I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
for keys, values in dict:
^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `dict.items()` and don't call your variable `dict`

Comment: Try this . You have to use dict.items() to get the key-value pairs.  'code'                                                                                                `dict = {'john': [1,2], 'peter': [3,4], 'stacy': [5,6], 'chad': [7,8]}

for keys, values in dict.items():
   print(f"{keys} has {values[0]} and {values[1]}"  `